# Unable to load a previously dumped pickle file in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

The implemented algorithm which I use is quite heavy and has three parts. Thus, I used pickle to dump everything in between various stages in order to do testing on each stage separately.

Although the first dump always works fine, the second one behaves as if it is size dependent. It will work for a smaller dataset but not for a somewhat larger one. (The same actually also happens with a heatmap I try to create but that's a different question) The dumped file is about 10MB so it's nothing really large.

The dump which creates the problem contains a whole class which in turn contains methods, dictionaries, lists and variables.

I actually tried dumping both from inside and outside the class but both failed. 
The code I'm using looks like this:

```
data = pickle.load(open("./data/tmp/data.pck", 'rb')) #Reads from the previous stage dump and works fine.
dataEvol = data.evol_detect(prevTimeslots, xLablNum) #Export the class to dataEvol
dataEvolPck = open("./data/tmp/dataEvol.pck", "wb") #open works fine
pickle.dump(dataEvol, dataEvolPck, protocol = 2) #dump works fine
dataEvolPck.close()
```

and even tried this:

```
dataPck = open("./data/tmp/dataFull.pck", "wb")
pickle.dump(self, dataPck, protocol=2) #self here is the dataEvol in the previous part of code
dataPck.close()
```

The problem appears when i try to load the class using this part:

```
dataEvol = pickle.load(open("./data/tmp/dataEvol.pck", 'rb'))
```

The error in hand is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
dataEvol = pickle.load(open("./data/tmp/dataEvol.pck", 'rb'))
ValueError: itemsize cannot be zero
```

Any ideas?
I'm using Python 3.3 on a 64-bit Win-7 computer. Please forgive me if I'm missing anything essential as this is my first question.

---

Answer:

### The problem was an empty numpy string in one of the dictionaries. Thanks Janne!!!

Comment: Do you have numpy strings in your data stucture? There's an open bug report concerning empty ones: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3926

Comment: Thank you for responding Janne. I use no strings with numpy. The peculiar thing is that it works fine with a subset of the same dataset. Could it be that it is unable to save a large dictionary and that it thus tries to load a corrupt file?

Comment: If you eliminate the subset that works fine, do you get the problem with the rest of the dataset? Try to narrow it down that way.

Comment: Could an empty key from a dict do this? I removed a few variables (which were most definitely not empty; checked via pyscripter) and this empty key from this one dictionary and everything seems to be fine now. Oh, and it never contained any numpy arrays, although i did use them to create a dictionary which was part of the class. My bad. I'm sorry if I was a little misleading.

Comment: What type is the empty key? Use `type(key)` to check.

Comment: It's a string. All the keys in that particular dict are strings.

Comment: Note that a `numpy.string_` looks just like normal string if print `repr()` for example.

Comment: You're absolutely right Janne. It was a numpy.string_ being carried on from an np.append i totally forgot about. Damn, I'm really sorry i wasted your time. I should have checked that out first! A million thanks!

Comment: Please post an answer and accept it. It's how the site is designed to work and gives you credit.

Answer (score 1):

It is a NumPy bug that has been fixed recently in this [pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5475). To reproduce it, try:

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np
cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(np.string_('')))
```