# pickle ValueError: itemsize cannot be zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unicode

**When loading a pickled dict -->**

**using pickle I get this error:**

```
ValueError: itemsize cannot be zero
```

**using cPickle I get this error:**

```
ValueError: ('itemsize cannot be zero', <built-in function scalar>,(dtype('<U'), ''))
```

**Dict looks something like this:**

```
{(u'foo', u'bar'): {'which': [1,2,3], 1:[[u'a', u'b', u'c'], [u'aa', u'bb', u'']]}}
```

the values to key 1 are numpy arrays converted to lists using .tolist().

The strings are unicode (I've accidentally encoded a number of ascii strings to unicode. I don't know if that has anything to do with any of this)

Both keys and values may contain u'' as values but are never containing only u'' items

I'm using python 2.7.5 and numpy 1.7.1

I'm not sure why the cPickle error is referencing a dtype. Is this something in the cPickle module or is it referring to my once numpy array that I converted to a list?

Comment: That dict pickles okay for me with 2.7.2.

Comment: You are correct. My example dict does not recreate the error. It was only meant to show the basic macro structure of the dictionary. I will edit my question to show some example code that throws the error I am concerned with.

Comment: False. I can't figure out how to recreate the error. The code that produces the dictionary is over 500 lines and takes about 1.5 hrs to run. My assumption is that it is somehow related to numpy and or my attempt at encoding.

Comment: Do you use `rb` and `wb` for the files?

Comment: yes. I have used 'wb' to write and 'rb' to read.

Comment: the file itself is about 20mb and when I open it with a text editor there is most certainly stuff in it. So the error is kind of confusing to me as I don't know what it is referring to. From what I have been able to google others attribute this error to numpy being involved in the processes but I'm confused why that would be an issue in my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all `u''` strings with a dummy char value and my problem was solved.

[Unable to load a previously dumped pickle file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366954/unable-to-load-a-previously-dumped-pickle-file-in-python?rq=1) offers a little more information regarding this problem. At some level it seems to be an issue with numpy and empty strings not playing nice with pickle,

Answer (score 3):

It is a NumPy bug that has been fixed recently in this [pull request](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5475). To reproduce it, try:

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np
cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(np.string_('')))
```